# Django : Multiple row form not being saved to the database

Tags: html, django, datatables

I have gone through the django docs and all similar questions, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a form that takes in the marks of multiple exams for multiple students in the form of a table (using data-tables).

What I basically need is to display a table that shows the values currently present in the database, but that also allows editing and saving. Also, although the entire table is displayed, it should allow editing only some of the table cells.

In the table, the students' roll numbers are from the database, but they don't change, so I don't pass them to the forms. The problem is even though there isn't any error, the `form.is_valid()` returns `true`, but `form.save()` doesn't save the values to the database.

What I suspect is that it probably doesn't know the roll number pertaining to the row of data that it received and can't place it in the database. I don't really know the mistake.Help will be deeply appreciated.Thank you.

**EDITED**
**table.html**

```html
 <form action="{% url 'score:markstable' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                         {% csrf_token %}
                        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ROLL NO</th>
                                    <th>IT1</th>
                                    <th>IT2</th>
                                    <th>CA</th>
                                    <th>AVG</th>
                                    <th>SEMESTER</th>
                                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                                    <th>STATUS</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% for marks in mrk %}

                            <tr>
                                <td width="73px">{{ marks.student }}</td>
                                <td><label for="IT1"></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="IT1" name="IT1" width="40px" min="0" max="20" value="{{ marks.IT1 }}"></td>
                                <td><label for="IT2"></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="IT2" name="IT2" width="40px" min="0" max="20" value="{{ marks.IT2 }}"></td>
                                <td><label for="CA"></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="CA" name="CA" width="30px" min="0" max="5" value="{{ marks.CA }}"></td>
                                <td><label for="Avg"></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="Avg" name="Avg" width="40px" min="0" max="25" value="{{ marks.Avg }}"></td>
                                <td><label for="Semester"></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="Semester" name="Semester" width="90px" min="0" max="100" value="{{ marks.Semester }}"></td>
                                <td><label for="total"></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="total" name="total" width="90px" min="0" max="850" value="{{ marks.total }}"></td>
                                <td><label for="status"></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="status" id="status" width="70px"value="{{ marks.status }}"></td>
                                </tr>

                            {% endfor %}

                            </tbody>
                         </table>&nbsp;
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="savebutton"><br>
                    </form>
```

**models.py**

```
class studentinfo(models.Model) :
    roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.roll_no

class marklist(models.Model) :
    student = models.ForeignKey(studentinfo, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    IT1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
    IT2 = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
    CA = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)])
    Avg = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MaxValueValidator(25), MinValueValidator(0)])
    Semester = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0)])
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(850), MinValueValidator(0)])
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**views.py**

```
def markstable(request):
    template = 'table.html'
    form = MarklistForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'score/index.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'score/index.html', {'error_message': 'Not Working'})
```

**forms.py**

```
class MarklistForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = marklist
        fields = ['IT1', 'IT2', 'CA', 'Avg', 'Semester', 'total', 'status']
```

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: what Django version are you using?

Comment: There is no error being displayed. The database values are not updated. I am using version 1.11.3

Comment: delete forms from forms.Modelforms. In Django 1.11 we don't have to put forms.ModelForm just ModelForm

Comment: If I only put ModelForm it says-
 NameError: name 'ModelForm' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is my answer first edit your view like this

```
def markstable(request):
    template = 'table.html'
    form = MarklistForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'score/index.html')

        else:
            return render(request, 'score/index.html', {'error_message': 'Not Working'})
   else:
       form = MarklistForm()
       return render(request. 'score/index.html', {'form':form})
```

And in your template you need to add the form like {% csrf_token %} {{form}}. You had that error because you didn't have a valid form in your html template, also you need check if is a post method, if is a post method you save the changes in your models, if not then you show the empty form. Tell me what happen

Comment: I am using data-tables so I need the table to have <td></td> .With {{form}} the whole table format is not possible and it displays a blank screen. I tried using {{form.as_table}} but that gives the same output as {{form}}

Comment: the problem is that you dont have the <form action="{% url 'your_url:name' %}" method="post"> also add the csrsf token and the submit   <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: I do,but since that part is not involved in displaying the form as a table i didn't include it..let me edit my code.

Comment: Ok now take the elements one by one, you can't just use form.save() because you have another form different from your model, then use a = request.POST['name of your label'] for get the value of each one and then add to the model b = Model(field=a) b.save()

Comment: I don't understand...by 'elements' do you mean the IT1,IT2..(the variables) or the records for each student ? And isn't my form and the model the same ?...could you please give a code snippet?..I'm really lost now..

Comment: Men delete or comment all the tag <tbody> and remplace with {{form}} and tell me what happened

Comment: remember pass the form in the context

Comment: I tried that , like you said earlier...it wont work...there arn't any errors but on using only {{form}} it does not display as a table .....just  a blank page without grids...and also I cannot use data-tables if I use only {{form}}

Comment: Like I said before take the inputs in your views.py like a = request.POST['IT1'] and then save like model = Marklist(student=.., IT1=a, .... and do one) model.save()

Comment: Your question is so wide, I tried to solved your problem, if you want pls give me an upvote